# What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86, micro-optimization

All the following instructions do the same thing: set `%eax` to zero. Which way is optimal (requiring fewest machine cycles)?

```
xorl   %eax, %eax
mov    $0, %eax
andl   $0, %eax
```

Comment: You might want to read this [article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/)

Comment: xor vs mov: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135679/does-using-xor-reg-reg-give-advantage-over-mov-reg-0

Answer (score 324, accepted):

**TL;DR summary**: `xor same, same` is the **best choice for all CPUs**.  No other method has any advantage over it, and it has at least some advantage over any other method.  It's officially recommended by Intel and AMD, and what compilers do.  In 64-bit mode, still use `xor r32, r32`, because [writing a 32-bit reg zeros the upper 32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  `xor r64, r64` is a waste of a byte, because it needs a REX prefix.

Even worse than that, Silvermont only recognizes `xor r32,r32` as dep-breaking, not 64-bit operand-size.  Thus **even when a REX prefix is still required because you're zeroing r8..r15, use `xor r10d,r10d`, not `xor r10,r10`**.

GP-integer examples:

```
xor   eax, eax       ; RAX = 0.  Including AL=0 etc.
xor   r10d, r10d     ; R10 = 0.  Still prefer 32-bit operand-size.

xor   edx, edx       ; RDX = 0
 ; small code-size alternative:    cdq    ; zero RDX if EAX is already zero

; SUB-OPTIMAL
xor   rax,rax       ; waste of a REX prefix, and extra slow on Silvermont
xor   r10,r10       ; bad on Silvermont (not dep breaking), same as r10d on other CPUs because a REX prefix is still needed for r10d or r10.
mov   eax, 0        ; doesn't touch FLAGS, but not faster and takes more bytes
 and   eax, 0        ; false dependency.  (Microbenchmark experiments might want this)
 sub   eax, eax      ; same as xor on most but not all CPUs; bad on Silvermont for example.

xor   cl, cl        ; false dep on some CPUs, not a zeroing idiom.  Use xor ecx,ecx
mov   cl, 0         ; only 2 bytes, and probably better than xor cl,cl *if* you need to leave the rest of ECX/RCX unmodified
```

---

Zeroing a vector register is usually best done with `pxor xmm, xmm`.  That's typically what gcc does (even before use with FP instructions).

`xorps xmm, xmm` can make sense.  It's one byte shorter than `pxor`, but `xorps` needs execution port 5 on Intel Nehalem, while `pxor` can run on any port (0/1/5).  (Nehalem's 2c bypass delay latency between integer and FP is usually not relevant, because out-of-order execution can typically hide it at the start of a new dependency chain).

On SnB-family microarchitectures, neither flavour of xor-zeroing even needs an execution port.  On AMD, and pre-Nehalem P6/Core2 Intel, `xorps` and `pxor` are handled the same way (as vector-integer instructions).

Using the AVX version of a 128b vector instruction zeros the upper part of the reg as well, so `vpxor xmm, xmm, xmm` is a good choice for zeroing YMM(AVX1/AVX2) or ZMM(AVX512), or any future vector extension.  `vpxor ymm, ymm, ymm` doesn't take any extra bytes to encode, though, and runs the same on Intel, but slower on AMD before Zen2 (2 uops).  The AVX512 ZMM zeroing would require extra bytes (for the EVEX prefix), so XMM or YMM zeroing should be preferred.

**XMM/YMM/ZMM examples**

```
    # Good:
 xorps   xmm0, xmm0         ; smallest code size (for non-AVX)
 pxor    xmm0, xmm0         ; costs an extra byte, runs on any port on Nehalem.
 xorps   xmm15, xmm15       ; Needs a REX prefix but that's unavoidable if you need to use high registers without AVX.  Code-size is the only penalty.

   # Good with AVX:
 vpxor xmm0, xmm0, xmm0    ; zeros X/Y/ZMM0
 vpxor xmm15, xmm0, xmm0   ; zeros X/Y/ZMM15, still only 2-byte VEX prefix

#sub-optimal AVX
 vpxor xmm15, xmm15, xmm15  ; 3-byte VEX prefix because of high source reg
 vpxor ymm0, ymm0, ymm0     ; decodes to 2 uops on AMD before Zen2


    # Good with AVX512
 vpxor  xmm15,  xmm0, xmm0     ; zero ZMM15 using an AVX1-encoded instruction (2-byte VEX prefix).
 vpxord xmm30, xmm30, xmm30    ; EVEX is unavoidable when zeroing zmm16..31, but still prefer XMM or YMM for fewer uops on probable future AMD.  May be worth using only high regs to avoid needing vzeroupper in short functions.
    # Good with AVX512 *without* AVX512VL (e.g. KNL / Xeon Phi)
 vpxord zmm30, zmm30, zmm30    ; Without AVX512VL you have to use a 512-bit instruction.

# sub-optimal with AVX512 (even without AVX512VL)
 vpxord  zmm0, zmm0, zmm0      ; EVEX prefix (4 bytes), and a 512-bit uop.  Use AVX1 vpxor xmm0, xmm0, xmm0 even on KNL to save code size.
```

See [Is vxorps-zeroing on AMD Jaguar/Bulldozer/Zen faster with xmm registers than ymm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713273/is-vxorps-zeroing-on-amd-jaguar-bulldozer-zen-faster-with-xmm-registers-than-ymm) and
[What is the most efficient way to clear a single or a few ZMM registers on Knights Landing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578967/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clear-a-single-or-a-few-zmm-registers-on-knigh)

Semi-related: [Fastest way to set __m256 value to all ONE bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469930/fastest-way-to-set-m256-value-to-all-one-bits) and
[Set all bits in CPU register to 1 efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently/45113467#45113467) also covers AVX512 `k0..7` mask registers. SSE/AVX `vpcmpeqd` is dep-breaking on many (although still needs a uop to write the 1s), but AVX512 `vpternlogd` for ZMM regs isn't even dep-breaking.  Inside a loop consider copying from another register instead of re-creating ones with an ALU uop, especially with AVX512.

But zeroing is cheap: xor-zeroing an xmm reg inside a loop is usually as good as copying, except on some AMD CPUs (Bulldozer and Zen) which have mov-elimination for vector regs but still need an ALU uop to write zeros for xor-zeroing.

---

## What's special about zeroing idioms like xor on various uarches

Some CPUs recognize `sub same,same` as a zeroing idiom like `xor`, but **all CPUs that recognize any zeroing idioms recognize `xor`**.  Just use `xor` so you don't have to worry about which CPU recognizes which zeroing idiom.

`xor` (being a recognized zeroing idiom, unlike `mov reg, 0`) has some obvious and some subtle advantages (summary list, then I'll expand on those):

- smaller code-size than `mov reg,0`.  (All CPUs)
- avoids partial-register penalties for later code.  (Intel P6-family and SnB-family).
- doesn't use an execution unit, saving power and freeing up execution resources.  (Intel SnB-family)
- smaller uop (no immediate data) leaves room in the uop cache-line for nearby instructions to borrow if needed.  (Intel SnB-family).
- [doesn't use up entries in the physical register file](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/).  (Intel SnB-family (and P4) at least, possibly AMD as well since they use a similar PRF design instead of keeping register state in the ROB like Intel P6-family microarchitectures.)

---

**Smaller machine-code size** (2 bytes instead of 5) is always an advantage: Higher code density leads to fewer instruction-cache misses, and better instruction fetch and potentially decode bandwidth.

---

The benefit of **not using an execution unit** for xor on Intel SnB-family microarchitectures is minor, but saves power.  It's more likely to matter on SnB or IvB, which only have 3 ALU execution ports.  Haswell and later have 4 execution ports that can handle integer ALU instructions, including `mov r32, imm32`, so with perfect decision-making by the scheduler (which doesn't always happen in practice), HSW could still sustain 4 uops per clock even when they all need ALU execution ports.

See [my answer on another question about zeroing registers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673696/224132) for some more details.

[Bruce Dawson's blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/) that Michael Petch linked (in a comment on the question) points out that `xor` is handled at the register-rename stage without needing an execution unit (zero uops in the unfused domain), but missed the fact that it's still one uop in the fused domain.  Modern Intel CPUs can issue & retire 4 fused-domain uops per clock.  That's where the 4 zeros per clock limit comes from.  Increased complexity of the register renaming hardware is only one of the reasons for limiting the width of the design to 4.  (Bruce has written some very excellent blog posts, like his series on [FP math and x87 / SSE / rounding issues](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/), which I do highly recommend).

---

**On AMD Bulldozer-family CPUs**, `mov immediate` runs on the same EX0/EX1 integer execution ports as `xor`.  `mov reg,reg` can also run on AGU0/1, but that's only for register copying, not for setting from immediates.  So AFAIK, on AMD the only advantage to `xor` over `mov` is the shorter encoding.  It might also save physical register resources, but I haven't seen any tests.

---

Recognized zeroing idioms **avoid partial-register penalties** on Intel CPUs which rename partial registers separately from full registers (P6 & SnB families).

`xor` will **tag the register as having the upper parts zeroed**, so `xor eax, eax` / `inc al` / `inc eax` avoids the usual partial-register penalty that pre-IvB CPUs have.  Even without `xor`, IvB and later only needs a merging uop when the high 8bits (`AH`) are modified and then the whole register is read.  (Agner incorrectly states that Haswell removes AH merging penalties.)

From Agner Fog's microarch guide, pg 98 (Pentium M section, referenced by later sections including SnB):

> The processor recognizes the XOR of a register with itself as setting
> it to zero. A special tag in the register remembers that the high part
> of the register is zero so that EAX = AL. This tag is remembered even
> in a loop:

```
    ; Example    7.9. Partial register problem avoided in loop
    xor    eax, eax
    mov    ecx, 100
LL:
    mov    al, [esi]
    mov    [edi], eax    ; No extra uop
    inc    esi
    add    edi, 4
    dec    ecx
    jnz    LL
```

> (from pg82): The processor remembers that the upper 24 bits of EAX are zero as long as
> you don't get an interrupt, misprediction, or other serializing event.

pg82 of that guide also confirms that `mov reg, 0` is *not* recognized as a zeroing idiom, at least on early P6 designs like PIII or PM.  I'd be very surprised if they spent transistors on detecting it on later CPUs.

---

**`xor` sets flags**, which means you have to be careful when testing conditions.  Since **`setcc` is unfortunately only available with an 8-bit destination** (until APX extension<sup>1</sup>), you usually need to take care to avoid partial-register penalties.

It would have been nice if x86-64 repurposed one of the removed opcodes (like AAM) for a 16/32/64 bit `setcc r/m`, with the predicate encoded in the source-register 3-bit field of the r/m field (the way some other single-operand instructions use them as opcode bits).  But they didn't do that, and that wouldn't help for x86-32 anyway.

Ideally, you should use `xor` / set flags / `setcc` / read full register:

```
...
call  some_func
xor     ecx,ecx    ; zero *before* setting FLAGS
cmp     eax, 42
setnz   cl         ; ecx = cl = (some_func() != 42)
add     ebx, ecx   ; no partial-register penalty here
```

This has optimal performance on all CPUs (no stalls, merging uops, or false dependencies).  (If the condition was `ebx += (eax != 0)`, there are tricks like `cmp eax, 1; sbb ebx, -1` using the carry flag with `adc` or `sbb` to add or subtract it directly, instead of materializing it as a 0/1 integer, as @l4m2 pointed out in comments.  It might even be worth it to do `sub eax, 42` (or LEA into another reg) / `cmp eax,1`  / `sbb`.  Especially if it's hard to arrange to xor-zero before setting FLAGS, since `cmp`/`setcc`/`movzx`/`add` has all 4 operations on the critical path for latency.)

**Things are more complicated when you don't want to xor before a flag-setting instruction**.  e.g. you want to branch on one condition and then setcc on another condition from the same flags.  e.g. `cmp/jle`, `sete`, and you either don't have a spare register, or you want to keep the `xor` out of the not-taken code path altogether.

There are no recognized zeroing idioms that don't affect flags, so the best choice depends on the target microarchitecture.  On Core2, inserting a merging uop might cause a 2 or 3 cycle stall.  It's cheaper on SnB, like 1 cycle at worst, and [Haswell and later don't rename partial registers separately from full regs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to).  Using `mov reg, 0` / `setcc` is probably best on recent CPUs, but would have a significant penalty on older Intel CPUs (Nehalem and earlier).  On newer CPUs it's close to as good as xor-zeroing, but has worse code-size than `movzx`.

Using `setcc` / `movzx r32, r8` is probably the best alternative for Intel P6, if you can't xor-zero ahead of the flag-setting instruction.  That should be better than repeating the test after an xor-zeroing.  (Don't even consider `sahf` / `lahf` or `pushf` / `popf`).  IvB and later (except for Ice Lake) can eliminate `movzx r32, r8` (i.e. handle it with register-renaming with no execution unit or latency, like xor-zeroing).  AMD Zen family can only eliminate regular `mov` instructions, so `movzx` takes an execution unit and has non-zero latency, making test/`setcc`/`movzx` worse than `xor`/test/`setcc`.
Also worse than test/`mov r,0`/`setcc` (but much better on older Intel CPUs with partial-register stalls).

Using `setcc` / `movzx` with no zeroing first is bad on AMD/P4/Silvermont, because they don't track deps separately for sub-registers.  There would be a false dep on the old value of the register.  **Using `mov reg, 0`/`setcc` for zeroing / dependency-breaking is probably the best alternative when `xor`/test/`setcc` isn't an option.**  At least for "hot" code where this is part of an important latency chain.  Otherwise go for `movzx` to save a bit of code size.

Of course, if you don't need `setcc`'s output to be wider than 8 bits, you don't need to zero anything.  However, beware of false dependencies on CPUs other than P6 / SnB if you pick a register that was recently part of a long dependency chain.  (And beware of causing a partial reg stall or extra uop if you call a function that might save/restore the register you're using part of.)

---

**`and` with an immediate zero** isn't special-cased as independent of the old value on any CPUs I'm aware of, so it doesn't break dependency chains.  It has no advantages over `xor` and many disadvantages.

It's useful only for writing microbenchmarks when you *want* a dependency as part of a latency test, but want to create a known value by zeroing and adding.

---

**See http://agner.org/optimize/ for microarch details**, including which zeroing idioms are recognized as dependency breaking (e.g. `sub same,same` is on some but not all CPUs, while `xor same,same` is recognized on all.)    `mov` does break the dependency chain on the old value of the register (regardless of the source value, zero or not, because that's how `mov` works).  `xor` only breaks dependency chains in the special-case where src and dest are the same register, which is why `mov` is left out of the list of *specially* recognized dependency-breakers.  (Also, because it's not recognized as a zeroing idiom, with the other benefits that carries.)

**Interestingly, the oldest P6 design (PPro through Pentium III) *didn't* recognize `xor`-zeroing as a dependency-breaker, only as a zeroing idiom for the purposes of avoiding partial-register stalls**, so in some cases it was worth using *both* `mov` and then `xor`-zeroing in that order to break the dep and then zero again + set the internal tag bit that the high bits are zero so EAX=AX=AL.

See Agner Fog's Example 6.17. in his microarch pdf.  He says this also applies to P2, P3, and even (early?) PM.   [A comment on the linked blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/#comment-2482) says it was only PPro that had this oversight, but I've tested on Katmai PIII, and @Fanael tested on a Pentium M, and we both found that it didn't break a dependency for a latency-bound `imul` chain.  This confirms Agner Fog's results, unfortunately.

**Footnote 1**: [Intel Advanced Performance Extensions (APX)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) introduces REX2 and EVEX forms of integer instructions, for 32 GPRs and new 3-operand forms of common instructions.  And finally a zero-extending ("zero-upper" aka ZU) form of `setcc r64`.  (Total instruction length of 6 bytes, using one of the spare bits in the EVEX prefix to encode legacy vs. zero-upper behaviour for register destinations.)

---

### TL:DR:

If it really makes your code nicer or saves instructions, then sure, zero with `mov` to avoid touching the flags, as long as you don't introduce a performance problem other than code size.  Avoiding clobbering flags is the only sensible reason for not using `xor`, but sometimes you can xor-zero ahead of the thing that sets flags if you have a spare register.

`mov`-zero ahead of `setcc` is better for latency than `movzx reg32, reg8` after (except on Intel when you can pick different registers), but worse code size.

Comment: Interesting. So it's not really 100% free. I mean even though it does not use a port it still costs a micro-op. That's a subtlety I missed in Agner's manual. Thanks! So it has zero latency but throughput is 4 (or 0.25 reciprocal throughput).

Comment: Most arithmetic instructions  OP  R,S are forced by an out of order CPU to wait for the content of register R to be filled by previous instructions with register R as a target; this is a data dependency.  The key point is that Intel/AMD chips have special hardware to *break* must-wait-for-data-dependencies on register R when XOR  R,R is encountered, and does not necessarily do so for other register zeroing instructions.  This means the XOR instruction can be scheduled for immediate execution, and this is why Intel/AMD *recommend* using it.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Yup, and just to avoid any confusion (because I have seen this misconception on SO), `mov reg, src` also breaks dep chains for OO CPUs (regardless of src being imm32, `[mem]`, or another register).  This dependency-breaking doesn't get mentioned in optimization manuals because it's not a special case that only happens when src and dest are the same register.  It *always* happens for instructions that don't depend on their dest.  (except for Intel's implementation of `popcnt/lzcnt/tzcnt` having a false dep on the dest.)

Comment: @Zboson: The "latency" of an instruction with no dependencies only matters if there was a bubble in the pipeline.  It's nice for mov-elimination, but for zeroing instructions the zero-latency benefit only comes into play after something like a branch mispredict or I$ miss, where execution is waiting for the decoded instructions, rather than for data to be ready.  But yes, mov-elimination doesn't make `mov` free, only zero latency.  The "not taking an execution port" part usually isn't important.  Fused-domain throughput can easily be the bottleneck, esp. with loads or stores in the mix.

Comment: According to Agner KNL does not recognize Independence of 64-bit registers. So `xor r64, r64` does not just waste a byte. As you say `xor r32, r32` is the best choice especially with KNL. See section 15.7 "Special cases of independence" in this micrarch manual if you want to read more.

Comment: @Zboson: I already started working on a KNL update for this answer after seeing that in Agner's update: need to point out that r32 is important even when it doesn't save a REX prefix (`xor r8d,r8d`).  But then I got side-tracked setting up my new Skylake i7-6700k desktop with 16G of DDR4-2666 RAM :)  Bit of an upgrade from 65nm Core2Duo, e.g. 8x faster video encoding with x264 (which has good tuning/optimization for Core2, unlike x265).  I'll get back to that edit Real Soon Now, since I still have the text saved.

Comment: I am getting a Skylake system soon as well. Boring! Well not if you are coming from Core2Duo. But now that I have access to KNL. I was highly disappointed in Skylake due to the lack of AVX512. So much that I quit thinking about x86 SIMD for a while. I know that internally Skylake changes the pipeline over Broadwell significantly (so I hear) even if the instruction sets does not change but still.

Comment: @Zboson: yeah, front-end bubbles should be a lot rarer with the increased uop-cache read bandwidth and increased legacy-decode throughput.  (But the 4-uop/clock frontend max is still the same).  More instructions running on more ports is potentially very cool.  If I want to tune code to be good on recent Intel before SKL, I'm worried that SKL will avoid bottlenecks that HSW/BDW still have :/  I considered buying worse hardware :P  We should take this to chat if you have any more to say.  (I don't ATM).  But I'd have to look how to create a chat when the comment thing doesn't offer the option.

Comment: I would look into Function Multiversioning (FMV) with GCC if you want to optimize for SKL as well as other archs.  See
https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/distributions/918275-looking-at-gnu-linux-s-performance-over-2016-with-intel-s-clear-linux?p=918435#post918435

Comment: @Zboson: I meant that code I tested/tuned on SKL might fail to avoid performance pitfalls for HSW or SnB, regardless of instruction-set choice.  The question isn't how to make different versions for HSW and SKL, it's how to tune the HSW version without testing on pre-SKL hardware.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/g/YPDTZN) of even newest `gcc` somewhat stupidly issuing a `mov reg, 0` rather than an `xor` for a simple function. Sure, it is probably doing that because it needs the flags preserved from the earlier `cmp`, but it could have just swapped the order! `clang` does fine, and `icc` also uses an `xor` but only gets part marks because it pointlessly includes a `mov esi, esi` in the critical path.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yeah, gcc does silly stuff like that sometimes.  I wonder if it comes out of trying to save a register for cases where the `cmp` can't be deferred.  (e.g. if it wanted to result in `esi`).  In other cases of gcc making worse code (like `setcc/movzx` instead of `xor/setcc`), it usually looks like an idiom designed to reduce register pressure, used even when there isn't any.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps there is no feedback mechanism for the register pressure: it uses some "typical" tradeoff while generating code, and then when it gets to the end of a function it doesn't go back and relax the assumption that there might be register pressure.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah exactly.  I'm not sure how "canned" some of its idioms are, but I imagine it's easier for a compiler to deal with `setcc/movzx` as a single thing that stays together, vs. having to add stuff to the function's internal representation to express "ok, we need an xor-zeroed register before the flag-setting", and maybe have a fallback in case that's hard to do.  (Although in most cases you'd expect it would just end up redoing a `test` or `cmp`).

Comment: ah, where's good old [MIPS, with its "zero register"](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html) when you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with negative entropy (less heat) when the register value is known? "The thermodynamic meaning of negative entropy" https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1009.1630/

Comment: @WesTurner: Not in a regular x86 CPU using CMOS logic, like Intel Sandybridge-family.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS#Power:_switching_and_leakage.  Running zeroing-idiom instructions uses about the same amount of power as running NOP instructions on SnB-family, cheaper than `mov`-immediate or a regular XOR, and probably less than any other instruction other than `pause`.  But still much more than sitting in low-power sleep.  Modern digital logic is very far from the information-theoretic limits of energy per computation, and nothing they do internally has negative cost.

Comment: I totally lose you when you hit on `setcc` what does that have to do with zeroing? How does that add to the `xor`-idiom?

Comment: @PeterCordes "See Agner Fog's Example 6.17. in his microarch pdf. He claims this also applies to P2, P3, and even (early?) PM, but I'm sceptical of that. A comment on the linked blog post says it was only PPro that had this oversight. It seems really unlikely that multiple generations of the P6 family existed without recognizing xor-zeroing as a dep breaker." I tested it on my Tualatin Pentium III and Dothan Pentium M by looping on 10× `imul eax, eax/xor eax, eax`, with the reasoning that if `xor` is dep-breaking then the loop will be throughput bound and latency bound if it's not…

Comment: …and on those CPUs the results are unambiguous: 50 cycles for each 22 instructions (i.e. one iteration), indicating a clear dependency chain; compare 10 cycles for each 22 instructions on more modern CPUs where `xor` is dependency breaking. So it's clear that Agner is correct here in that `xor` is *not* dependency breaking on Pentium II/III and Pentium M. It may have changed in Yonah, the last generation of Pentium M sold as Core Solo and Core Duo (note, not Core ***2***), but I don't have that hardware to test.

Comment: @Fanael: Thanks, I should have updated this a while ago. I checked on a Katmai PIII and found it wasn't dep-breaking a while ago, but never finished editing an update.  Made one now to fix the two major things I left out.

Comment: "so in some cases it was worth using *both*." I am unclear on what the other one is meant as here, aside the `xor`-zeroing. Is it `mov` with immediate? And would you do them in the order `mov reg, 0` \ `xor reg, reg`, or the other way around?

Comment: @ecm: Yes, zero the reg and break the dependency on the old value with `mov reg, 0`, then zero it again and set the internal EAX = AX = AL tag bit (avoiding partial-register stalls) with `xor reg,reg`.  i.e. the "upper bits zeroed" tag.  IDK why xor-zeroing didn't break the dependency; maybe recognizing that in the decoders or issue stage would have taken extra logic vs. handling it only in the boolean logic execution unit?  But AFAIK it only worked with `xor same,same`, not just any xor that happened to produce `0`, and the ALU doesn't know if its inputs came from a reg, mem, or immed.

Comment: Thanks! Will you edit your answer to make that part clearer?

Comment: @ecm: I think the context for that "both" got lost in previous edits; fixed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: To increase `ebx` by 1 iff `eax` is not zero, is `mov ecx, eax; add ecx, -1; adc ebx, 0` shorter and faster?

Comment: `cmp eax, 1; sbb ebx, -1` enough

Comment: @l4m2: Good point, I should update the example to test for a condition like `x == 4`  or `x & 0x88` that doesn't allow optimization to get the condition in CF for `adc` or `sbb`

Comment: `and mem, dword 0` is 3 bytes shorter than `mov mem, dword 0` and 1 byte shorter than `xor eax, eax/mov mem, eax`, which may be useful to fit in small area

Comment: @l4m2: True, but I think this answer is already long and dense enough just talking about registers. :/  `and dword mem, 0` is also slower, with a false dependency on the old value of memory, so usually *only* useful for code-size optimization at the expense of speed.  Post in [Tips for golfing in x86 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) if it's not there already.  (Coding style: I think it makes a lot more sense to put the size override on the memory operand, not the immediate, especially to distinguish from things like `and eax, strict dword 0` to request an imm32 encoding.)

Comment: "It would have been nice if x86-64 repurposed one of the removed opcodes (like AAM) for a 16/32/64 bit setcc r/m, with the predicate encoded in the source-register 3-bit field of the r/m field (the way some other single-operand instructions use them as opcode bits). But they didn't do that, and that wouldn't help for x86-32 anyway." I think the new APX extensions will provide a `setcc r64`, right?

Comment: @ecm: Correct on all counts, and yes there's no way to fix x86-32 after 386 made the mistake(?) of providing setcc r/m8 instead of setcc r/m16/32 (storing a bool to memory is rare and can be easily done with a temp register).  `setcc r/m16` wouldn't be very valuable, so APX providing `setcc.zu full_reg` via an EVEX for the same opcodes solves the same problem for the only important case, at the cost of larger code-size than my proposed way.  It would've been nice if the REX2 encoding defaulted to zero-extend so a full 4-byte EVEX prefix would only be needed to *not* do that w. r16-r31.